# Reliability of creating and setting a cookie in GTM based on whether a user visits different pages?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have two separate websites on different domains and want to track whether a user is a visitor/member to one via a cookie , so we can use that to influence their experience on the other site. Currently, I have GTM setting a cookie based on whether the user has visited certain pages but I'm tracking the effectiveness of this with a combination of events in GTM and Google Analytics and there looks like a 10% error. I'm fairly new to both GA and GTM so it could be either errors on GTMs side or GAs side. I was wondering if anyone had any experience with setting cookies in GTM and if you think this is a safe way to set the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

The reliability of a cookie set by GTM is not a question.

The real question here is how you conduct your analysis, plus how you expect the said cookies to work.

1. Cookies are useless across top-level domains for this purpose, so if the cookies are set on one domain, they won't be seen on the other.
2. You're supposed to reset the cookie on every pageview to not lose the context of the visit.
3. In case you're measuring your tracking effectiveness against the access log, you have to keep in mind that quite a lot of people use adblockers. 10% of data loss due to adblockers sounds reasonable to me, in case you have a younger or more technically apt audience.
4. You may skip on edge cases when people visit site A from a normal source, then go to site B, so you set the cookie, but then they go back to site A from site B, and so you reset the cookie again.

I would suggest solving this either with referrer report in GA, or by joining the GTM tracking across the sites via [GTM cross-domain linking](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469?hl=en) and then analyzing unbroken user sessions, paying attention to the hostname dimension, and then building your analysis on top of that. If you need to track users being logged in on other site, you can then use a custom dimension for that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - these are a lot of points I didn't think about. We actually do have GTM cross-domain linking so the cookie is correctly showing on each site when I test it. I've just been questing whether it's working because of the data I'm tracking in GA. The cookie gets set if they visit site A, so to test it, I created a dummy element on site B that only shows if this cookie from site A is set. I'm then sending events from GTM to GA that saw which element on site B is shown. I segment this report based on whether the user visited  site A then site B.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to test it though – I'm looking into the methods you mentioned in your comment. I haven't been able to find many resources on how to go about this so I really appreciate your insight!

Comment: I'm not sure how you're reading the cookie from the other site. You're not supposed to be able to, unless they're on the same TLD, so just subdomains of the same domain.

Comment: I believe they are – so one site is www.site.com and the other is studio.site.com

Comment: oh then yes, in this case the cookies would work. Makes sense.